# How to pass query through an Ajax request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wamp

I'm working on paginating some data with Ajax requests. When one of the page number buttons is pressed it will send a request to a separate file to generate the next page in a table.

On my main page I'll have something like:

```
$query = "Select * from table WHERE field =  'something' LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// dump results as table
```

When I write the script to create a new xmlhttp request object to my "paginate.php" file, how can I carry this same query over to the file since it may dynamically change based on user input?

I was thinking of just passing the whole query string as a function parameter via a POST request, but am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Why dont you just pass the argument, and in php, use mysqli prepared statments ?

Comment: You absolutly do not want in any manner have your queries exposed in javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of just passing the whole query string as a function
>   parameter via a POST request

Definitely **do not** do this!  It's really *really* bad security practice to let the browser (ie. user) run queries directly against your database. I made this mistake in early days and my site got 0wned in no time.

Your PHP file should accept parameters, validate them, then use them to run the query

**1.** You XHR object sends: `page_number=5`

**2.** Your PHP validates the input and dynamically builds the query:

```
//set page to 1 if none was provided. 
$pg = isset($_POST['page_number'])? (int)$_POST['page_number']: 1;
$pg = max(1,$pg); // lowest allowed pg number is 1
```

Once you have the page number, and you are sure it's an integer (not some nefarious SQL command that a user sent to your server), you can use it in your query:

```
$size = 5; //# of results per page
$start = ($pg-1) * 5;   
$query = "SELECT * from myTable WHERE field='something' LIMIT $start,$size";
```

Note that if the field value `something` comes from the user, you don't want to include it in the query directly (this goes for any user-supplied value).  Instead, you should use *prepared statements* and *parameterized queries*

Resource: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Thank you for the link and info! I understand what you were saying in the answer perfectly, but it looks like I will need to research about prepared statements and come back to this!

Comment: @TimothyFisher no problem. Happy coding.